# Setting a button value in session scope

Tags: jsp

I am trying to set the value in session scope but it is not setting please find the problem exception is coming:

`<%String name=request.getParameter("name");%><% if(request.getParameter("name").equals(name)){session.setAttribute("EmployeeById",name);}%>`

Here you can find the code actually I want to set the button value in session and I am getting on other jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" %>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function popuponclick() {
            var mywindow = window.open("file.jsp", "file", "status=1,width=350,height=150");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
    <%String name = request.getParameter("name");%>

    <% if (request.getParameter("name").equals(name)) {
        session.setAttribute("EmployeeById", name);
    }
    %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" onclick="popuponclick()" value="GetEmployeeById" name="name"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="GetEmp" value="1"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" onclick="popuponclick()" value="GetEmployeeByname" name="name1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my second .jsp is this where i m getting the value through session scope

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml"%>
<%@page
    import="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.EmployeeBO"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<%
    String attributeValue = (String)session.getAttribute("EmployeeById");
out.println(attributeValue);
%>
<body>




<% if ("GetEmployeeById".equals(attributeValue)) { %>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>GetEmployeeByName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="GetEmployeeByName"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<% } else { %>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>GetEmployeeById</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="GetEmployeeById"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<% } %>
<table>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="find"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RavindraBagale NullPointer Exception

Comment: Where exactly you are getting that NPE?

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis i m adding my another jsp where i m getting value through session scope but i m getting exception on this <%String name=request.getParameter("name");%>

    <% if(request.getParameter("name").equals(name)){
    session.setAttribute("EmployeeById",name);}
    %> line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing:

Are you aware that even if you do not get the exception, this code makes no sense? You are getting the name parameter, then you getting it again and checking with the same value. This condition will always be `true`.

Second thing:

The code like:

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
session.setAttribute("EmployeeById", name);
```

Should be used in the servlets, not in JSP pages. In JSP page to get the value from the request, session or application scope you can use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

For e.g.:

```
${requestScope['name']}
```

This is the correct way of getting the request attribute in the JSP page.

The reason you are getting `NPE`, is because the request is not yet available in your JSP page and it is `null`. First you need to check if the request is not `null` and if it is not than do something with it.

Check [SO Servlets Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) page also.

Answer (score 0):

try this <%! String name=request.getParameter("name");%>

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis can u tell me how we can call one java script funtion of on jsp page to another java script function of other jsp page